# Can i get a part of an variable?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Is it possible to get an part of a variable and run this to a where loop.

```
function rapport_detail_kosten($idKlant){
            $this->db->from('Project');
                $this->db->join('Kosten', 'Kosten.idProject = Project.idProject');

if ($idKlant > 0){
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);}
        $query = $this->db->get();
            $project = array();
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
             $project[] = $row->idProject;
        }
        $hoi = implode(",", $project);
            print_r($hoi);
        $this->db->select_sum('Prijs'); 
        $this->db->from('Kosten');
        $this->db->where('Kosten.idProject',$hoi);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
         }
        else{
             return false;
         }
     }
```

the `$hoi` has the value: `14,79,9,85,85,85,85,91,6`
these are all id's but i would like to run this where statement only when the id is in this variable. So i would like to run id=6 but for example not `id=7`

Comment: try to use in_array before execute where to check if it is presented or not

Comment: also try to indent/format your code better, find a standard (like the pear standard) and follow it

Comment: So `$hoi` = '14,79,9,85,85,85,85,91,6' and `$idKlant` is the id. If `$idKlant` is in `$hoi`, then run the `where` statement. Is this what you want?

Comment: $idKlant is another id from the Table Klant. $hoi is the array of the Table 'Kosten' and then the id. and yes thats what i would like to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `where_in` of codeigniter that search a value inside an array, in this case you can use directly `$project`, you don't need `$hoi`

try this:

```
 $sum = 0;
 $this->db->select_sum('Prijs'); 
 $this->db->from('Kosten');
 $this->db->where_in('Kosten.idProject',$project);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 foreach ($query->result() as $row){
     $sum = $row->Prijs;
 }

 return($sum);
```

[**MANUAL**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: This is the same thing i've tried already but when i have an id which isnt in the table Kosten.idProject. but with the same Klant.idKlant. then it gets the same sum. I need to have the output NUll or 0 when its not in the array